# Weak convergence = norm convergence for trace class operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, trace, compact-operators

Given a (separable) Hilbertspace $H$, I look at the traceclass operators $\mathfrak{S}_1$. I recall the fact that the weak convergence implies norm convergence in the sequence space $\mathcal{l}^1$. Does this also hold for $\mathfrak{S}_1$ which is $$\text{tr }(|A-A_j|)\to 0 \text{ if and only if  } \text{tr }K(A-A_j)\to 0\; \forall K\in B(H) ?$$

Comment: I don't know if the statement is true as stated. But if you additionally assume that $\|A_j\|_1 \longrightarrow \|A\|_1$, then the result is contained in this paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1981-083-01/S0002-9939-1981-0619978-4/S0002-9939-1981-0619978-4.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I knew that one. One can actually deduce from $\|A_j\|_1 \to \|A\|$ and $A_j\to A$ in the WOT that $A_j \to A$ in $\mathfrak{S}_1$.

Comment: I also asked this question on mathoverflow. The answer is negative: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/228918/weak-convergence-implies-norm-convergence-for-trace-class-operators/228939#228939

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{e_n\}$ be ONS. $A_j=e_j\otimes e_1.$ If $K\in L(H),$ then $tr(KA_j)=(e_j, Ke_1)\to 0.$ But $||A_j||_1=1.$

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Oleg, this is not true. What however *does* hold is the following (Proposition 2 in *On the Families of Gibbs Semigroups* by V.A. Zagrebnov, CMP 1980):

If $(C_k)$ is a sequence of self-adjoint trace-class operators and $C$ is a further trace-class operator, then weak convergence of $C_k$ to $C$ implies trace class convergence of $C_k$ to $C$ provided additionally

- $|C_k|$ converges weakly to $|C|$; and
- the trace class norm of $C_k$ converges to the trace class norm of $C$.